# Get first element from tag name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am converting standard JavaScript over to jQuery for cross browser compatibility. I just want to know how will this be written in jQuery? In other words how do I find the first element?

```
var x = content.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.data;
```

I have tried the following:

```
var content = $.parseXML(zipEntry1.data);
content = $(content);
var x = content.find("title").first().val();
```

and

```
var content = $.parseXML(zipEntry1.data);
content = $(content);
var x = content.find("title")[0].val();
```

But none of those work. What would be the correct way?

**EDIT:**

Here is some additional info. I am writing a Epub reader. The file I am parsing is content.opf within the Epub specification. Here is an extract:

```
<metadata>
<dc:rights>Public domain in the USA.</dc:rights>
<dc:identifier id="id" opf:scheme="URI">http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/6130</dc:identifier>
<dc:contributor opf:file-as="Buckley, Theodore Alois" opf:role="ann">Theodore Alois Buckley</dc:contributor>
<dc:creator opf:file-as="Homer">Homer</dc:creator>
<dc:contributor opf:file-as="Pope, Alexander" opf:role="trl">Alexander Pope</dc:contributor>
<dc:title>The Iliad</dc:title>
<dc:language xsi:type="dcterms:RFC4646">en</dc:language>
<dc:subject>Classical literature</dc:subject>
<dc:subject>Epic poetry, Greek -- Translations into English</dc:subject>
<dc:subject>Achilles (Greek mythology) -- Poetry</dc:subject>
<dc:subject>Trojan War -- Poetry</dc:subject>
<dc:date opf:event="publication">2004-07-01</dc:date>
<dc:date opf:event="conversion">2012-10-31T19:41:56.338029+00:00</dc:date>
<dc:source>http://www.gutenberg.org/files/6130/6130-h/6130-h.html</dc:source>
```

I can get the author and title with this, but it only works in Chrome:

```
content.find('creator:first').text();
content.find('title:first').text();
```

Version works in Firefox and Chrome:

```
content.find("package").attr("version");
```

And I have not yet got the publication date. This is what I tried:

```
 content.find('[event="publication"]').val();
```

Comment: this does not look like jQuery.

Comment: I am sorry. I will add more code

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the text content of the first title use this:

```
$('title:first', content).text();
```

However jQuery in Firefox require namespace to be specified as well:

```
var ff = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
$((ff ? 'dc\\:' : '') + 'title:first', content).text();
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/enayex/5/edit

Comment: This solution only worked in Chrome and not in Firefox. My target group mainly uses Firefox.

Comment: @EduanBekker I've just tested this solution in FireFox 19.0.2 and 20.0 on my Mac and it worked, see http://jsbin.com/enayex/1/edit. Can  you post a part of XML you have?

Comment: I will post the XML in the main question.

Comment: @EduanBekker For Firefox you need to specify namespace in jQuery selector in order to make it work.

Comment: Don't know why Firefox needs namespace to be specified, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
var x = content.find('title:first').html()
```

or

```
var x = content.find('title:first').text();
```

Comment: Think he's after the attr?  (never seen a page w/more than one title tag.

Comment: Remember the context, though. He already has an object `content` he's using for the `getElementsByTagName`, so it needs to be `$("title:first", content);`

Comment: Ah yes new info... I had assumed that `content` was the document.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch, it looks like he's going after an xml document.

Comment: The second one with .text() only worked in Chrome and not in Firefox. My target group mainly uses Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the element type then this can be easy. Let us assume that we are dealing with divs, then do this:

```
$('div').first().html("<p>I found you</p>");
```